# Access Based Enumeration Issue

Tags: network-share

I seem to be having an issue when using Access Based Enumeration with Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 (I don't have a 7 machine to try this on sadly).

The share is set up and has ABE enabled.

I have given the share 'Travel Documents' List Folder & Traverse Folder rights.

I have a 'Test Rep Folder' in there that only 1 account can access (Admin). However, when I try to test the ABE on my W10 machine - accessing via the mapped drive, it still shows the folder but gives access denied when trying to enter it (At least the permissions bit works).

If I navigate to it using the UNC path, I still see the folder and get the same error.

If I try this on my Server 2012 machine, the folder is still visible via the drive share, however not via the UNC path.

I have set up access groups on the folders to control access, but it seems that the ABE doesn't work in W10 or on Server 2012 via the mapped drive. I have seen this work in a corporate environment with W7 and Server 2008 machines (I do this stuff daily and it's so boring - so at least I know it works in some environments).

Folder structure is as follows:

Travel Documents (Share. ABE enabled. Controlled via DLG [List/Traverse] with GLO added to DLG. All users have access to this T group)

|--Test Rep Folder (Controlled via DLG with GLO added to DLG. Admin user is in RXWD GLO. No other users are in here or the RX groups.)

In the Travel documents share, Admin and Standard can see the Test Rep Folder - even though it should be hidden from Standard

Standard can see Test Rep Folder via mapped drive:

[image: Standard can see Test Rep Folder via mapped drive]

Standard can see Test Rep Folder via UNC path:

[image: Standard can see Test Rep Folder via UNC path]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to a W7 machine and ABE works as intended there from S2012.

Seems to be an issue with W10. Go figure!